# How to make floating scroll bar (handy-scroll) work with LitElement?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar, lit-element

Ok, so I don't actually know that the problem is with LitElement but it's the only thing I can think of that might break it.

I'm trying to use [handy-scroll](https://github.com/Amphiluke/handy-scroll) to have a floating scroll bar. I want to scroll vertically over legend and diagram (which are horizontally next to each other, legend as in a geographic map's legend) and have the floating scroll bar over the diagram being able to horizontally scroll the diagram. The setup is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/bundle.css">
<div class="" style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 200px;">
    <lv-legend style="display: inline-block;"></lv-legend>
    <div id="handscrolls" style="display: inline-block;">
        <lv-diagram style="display: inline-block; width: 500px;"></lv-diagram>
    </div>
</div>
<lv-menu style="display: block;"></lv-menu>
```

The elements starting with "lv" are my custom elements. lv-diagram contains an svg that is updated regularly. For this reason I mount and update the scroll bar as it says on their github but from the LitElement callback functions:

```
updated(changedProperties) {
    let handscrollsContainer = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("handscrolls");
    handyScroll.update(handscrollsContainer);
}

firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
    let handscrollsContainer = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("handscrolls");
    handyScroll.mount(handscrollsContainer);
    console.log("the mounting was successful: "+ handyScroll.mounted(handscrollsContainer));
}
```

I have tried various permutations of where the handyScroll is mounted but it just doesn't want to work.

It does get attached as a child of the `<div id="handscrolls">` with classes `class="handy-scroll handy-scroll-hidden"` and height 0. But it is not usable and not displayed.

It also appears to break my width-constraint, gladly displaying the diagram further to the right off the screen.

Even if you have no solution, any ideas are welcome at this point. Thank you for taking the time.